# Flutter for web how to store credentials?

Tags: web, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am building a Flutter For Web Application that needs to store the credentials in a secure way, to allow the user to automatically login, how can i achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typical web applications (whether flutter_web or not), it is not wise to actually store the user's password in the browser in a cookie or in html storage. One technique some use is to have a persistent cookie that stores the username and a temporary authentication token of some kind that is encrypted with a private key. The authentication token is temporary but exists on the user record in the database and can be used during the time it is allowed to be valid in place of the user's password. This way the user's credentials aren't persisted in the web browser - only the username and the token in an encrypted, persistent cookie.

From what appears to be in the dev preview of Flutter web is that it produces web applications, and I am assuming that standard web development techniques for user security for any and all web applications should be used.

Comment: So if i use nodejs + express + express-session and make a simple login i am ok?

Comment: Yes. You have to decide with express-session if you are going to use the session based or token based (JWT) management. And, you still will have build something to persist a token client side to have the persistent login you described with either approach. FWIW, at my company, we always use the token based session management because it is more lightweight for the server. Our web clients have to put the JWT in the http headers with every request.  You're on the right track with a lib like express-session. Good luck.

Comment: I wasn't sure if to use express-session or jwt, but i will do as you said thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package
Seems to me it supports both web and android
https://pub.dev/packages/password_credential